# Change subnet on TP-LINK TD-W8961ND

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dhcp

I don't seem to be able to change the subnet on my router (spoiler alert - I'm not terribly good with networks so I would appreciate the help!).

When I change the main IP address to 192.168.10.1 and the starting address to 192.168.10.100, I am prompted with this message:

[image]

However, once I click *OK*, nothing seems to happen. I've checked in Chrome DevTools to see if any requests are being sent - nothing.

What does seem to work is if I disable DHCP, set the main IP address - then connect to the new IP address; however I then cannot reactivate DHCP and it won't even let me add static IPs with my MAC address.

If I try to change the Router Local IP first, before changing the DHCP settings, I get this error upon attempting to save:

[image]

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Edit: The page I am using looks like this, and has the following values:
[image]

Comment: Try changing the main & starting addresses while leaving DHCP on, then reboot the router and afterward the PC. If this doesn't work, try the [latest firmware](http://www.tp-link.com/en/support/download/?model=TD-W8961ND); you will need to restore to factory defaults to make it take effect.

Comment: Like I said in my initial question, I can't even change the main IP.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Is there an error message, or can't you type inside the field?

Comment: OK, you have added the error message. You need to change every `192.168.1` on the page to `192.168.9`. Turn off all devices for which you can't do that (except of course the PC). Please also post a screenshot of the relevant page at the moment you are trying to save, [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/X1AnS.jpg).

Comment: Screenshot added. Also please note that I cannot use the 192.168.9.x subnet - 8 or anything above 9 will do

Comment: The screenshot you have posted contains the default values. Please post instead that of the screen after you have made your changes and for which pressing the Save button will cause this error message. And do you mean that you can change to 192.168.7 but not to 192.168.8?

Comment: First disable DHCP, save, change Router IP, save.

Answer (score 1):

Here was how I did it. Without updating firmware. For some reason,  it is not possible for me to update firmware.

1. Change the subnet into 255.255.0.0
2. At the dhcp table, add my mac into static mode.
3. Press save.
4. Change dhcp setting to your requirement
5. at the dhcp table, add my address to auto mode.
6. Press save.
7. Disconnect and reconnect your wifi client to obtain a new ip.
8. change your modem ip address and subnet to the correct setting.

Seem like only the change in dhcp table will trigger the save function of the page,  thus will save any change you made at the page.

ps. I forgot on which step,  but there might be time when there is nothing in the dhcp table, just enter any random mac address. I used aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff.

hope can helped some with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were simply getting ahead of yourself.

Instead of changing both, only change the IP address under "Router Local IP", then click "Save".  Wait 1-2 minutes, then release and renew the IP address on your computer (or unplug the cable and plug it back in if that's easier for you).  If you get a 192.168.9.x address, then you're done.  If you get a 192.168.1.x address, then try power-cycling the router (unplug the power and plug it back in).  If you don't get an address at all, then try setting a 192.168.9.x address statically (e.g. 192.168.9.77), and then see if you can connect to your router again to setup DHCP.

If you're still having difficulties, try upgrading the firmware on your router.  Make sure you check the hardware version of your router before you choose which one to [download](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TD-W8961ND#down).

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work - see my edit to the original question (since I can't upload images in comments)

Comment: @infomaniac Ok, so change both, wait 1 minute, then power cycle your router.

Answer (score 0):

You're making headway.  That's great.

It may be best if you really treat the changing of the IPv4 address, and the changing of the DHCP settings, as two separate things.  When you changed the router's IPv4 address, you succeeded in that step.  Good.

After changing the IPv4 address, you need to be able to communicate with the router at 192.168.9.1.  To do that, your computer needs to have an address that starts with "192.168.9."  (I am making an assumption of /24 networks, which means that your subnet mask is "255.255.255.0", which is not strictly necessary but is what is common.)  The easy way to accomplish this might be to set your computer's address to "192.168.9.50" (as a statically-assigned address), at least temporarily.

Then, using 192.168.9.addresses, change the DHCP settings to your heart's content.  Re-enable DHCP, and tell it that 192.168.9.100 should be the starting address in the range of addresses to hand out (if you want to, which looks like is what you were trying to do).

Note that once DHCP is re-enabled, your computer won't make any changes automatically.  You may need to flip your computer back to using DHCP, to perform a renew (which might involve a process of performing a release first).  In Windows Vista+, you can "Repair" the network adapter.  If all else fails, you can restart the equipment (reboot the computer), because that is an overkill method that usually results in a new DHCP request.  Until your computer does this, your computer won't be affected by any DHCP changes you make on the router.  The changes on the router simply affect what responses the router will give; that has no effect until the other devices make another request to the router asking for a response.  That is why nothing happened when you pushed OK.

If the router allows you to change the router's Local IP address before changing the DHCP settings, then that will break DHCP until those DHCP settings are fixed.  The rule is that the DHCP addresses that get handled out need to be part of the same subnet.  (That rule might be able to be violated, but that actually ends up being more complicated.  To keep things simple, follow that rule.)  Being part of the same subnet basically means that the first numbers are sufficiently close.  For a /24-sized network (which is what you're using if you have a 255.255.255.0 subnet mask), that means the numbers before the first three periods must match exactly.  (That's why everyone likes to use 255.255.255.0 ; it allows people to very easily tell whether addresses are part of the same subnet.)

Comment: I am *not* able to change my router's IP address. That is my entire issue right now.

Comment: The 192.168.9 subnet will not work for me - I either need it to be 192.168.8.x or anything higher than 9. Basically I need to connect my company's VPN and they have IP allocations in those ranges already

Comment: Regarding first comment: Then you're being inconsistent.  Your question says "When I change the main IP address to 192.168.9.1", and "What does seem to work is if I disable DHCP, set the main IP address - then connect to the new IP address".  But now you say you are "<I>not</I> able to change my router's IP address."  Regarding your next comment: There's nothing magical about 192.168.9 that caused me to specify that, other than that is what you used for your examples.  Use another 192.168.soemthing.something subnet if you prefer.

Comment: Sorry TOOGAM, you're quite right. I will update the question. The problem is that I can only change the main IP if I disable DHCP, but then I cannot enable DHCP again.

Comment: From that screen: Get rid of the Manual Config/Static in the DHCP table.  That's just trouble, for now; re-add it much later.  Then, change the IP address to 192.168.10.1, then make sure DHCP Server Starting IP address is 192.168.10.100 then click Save.  If that fails, then just disable the DHCP server, and just change the IP address and click Save.  If you get a window saying to press OK, then do that. Then make your computer use 192.168.10.2 and visit http://192.168.10.1. Then, by DHCP, make it Enabled and have the Starting IP address 192.168.10.100. Then re-add static MAC with a 192.168.10.

Comment: So here's the thing... I disable DHCP and change the Router IP to 192.168.10.1. Great, so now I assign myself a fixed IP of 192.168.10.2 and access the console. Now, when i try to re-enable DHCP, it won't let me proceed... I click save, but it does not allow me to save until I've added a DHCP record, but I cannot. There is a dropdown of available IP addresses, but that is blank, and I can't manually configure it. Here's where I get stuck every time

Comment: Exact text (even another screenshot) may be beneficial.  Note: If you add a screenshot to question, please also add a note why you're using 192.168.10.something (because you're following advice from this answer), otherwise people reading the edited question may be confused until/if they see my answer.  Technically, the DHCP issue slightly fits the description of being a separate and distinct question from the original, though I understand that all these issue are related.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you update your PC's IP after changing starting IP in router? Because router holds a table of know MAC-addresses and every time you try to assign new address you will get the same IP you got last time.

As first step in process you have to change routers IP, move it to another subnet.
Then you have to release and renew DHCP lease on you client. After renewing IP on router you should be disconnected from it (because of wrong IP settings), and when you flush your DNS settings on clients and reconnect to your router and you should get new address in new IP-subnet.

Release / renew:

> Mac OS: https://support.apple.com/en-us/ts1920
>
> Linux Ubuntu:
>   http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1654621&p=10289517#post10289517
>
> Windows: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490921.aspx